# In LINQ-TO-SQL, how do union or join to a row of text not from the database?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to expand my results by joining to a row of text, not data from a table.
For example:

```
from c in db.customers
join x in (
  select new
  {
    custType = "A"
  }
).Union(
  select new
  {
    custType = "B"
  }
).Union(
  select new
  {
    custType = "C"
  }
)
on 1 equals 1
select new
{
   c.CustomerName,
   x.custType
}
```

This would provide the list of customers three times, each with a different custType specified.  How do I create this temporary "x" table from the example?

I've tried specifying an actual table, but if I don't return any rows from the table, it gives the error:

> The member '<>f__AnonymousTyped7`2[System.String,System.String].custType'
>   has no supported translation to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var queryA = from customer in db.customers
             select new {
                 customer.CustomerName,
                 custType = "A"
             };
var queryB = from customer in db.customers
             select new {
                 customer.CustomerName,
                 custType = "B"
             };
var queryC = from customer in db.customers
             select new {
                 customer.CustomerName,
                 custType = "C"
             };

var result = queryA.Union(queryB).Union(queryC);
```

You might want to create a class to contain the customer name and type properties instead of relying on an anonymous one. That's kind of a choice of preference as well as how many places it will be reused.

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility.  The example I posted is an oversimplification so I can show what I'm wanting to do in a much more complex query.  I may have to try and break it out as you have shown.  I also had hoped to improve performance by running just one query and limiting returned results with my joins.

Comment: I guess the point to take away is that you want to take advantage of deferred execution as much as possible. Unlike traditional SQL, with LINQ it often makes sense to build your query in smaller, simple pieces so that it's easy to follow.